# Programmatically check RadioButton

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view, android-radiobutton

I have two radiobutton groups that need to be initialized when loading the screen, so I used this code:

```
 mVisibilityPublic.setChecked(true);
```

But when I load the screen I get the following (first is the wrong behavior, second is the expected one):

[image]

I've tried with all these:

```
    mVisibilityPublic.setSelected(true);
    mVisibilityPublic.performClick();
    mVisibilityPublic.setActivated(true);
    mVisibilityPublic.invalidate();
    mVisibilityPublic.requestLayout();
```

But I get the same result.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/form_vertical_spacing"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context=".createevent.CreateEventActivity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/create_event_privacy"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/create_visibility_group"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp">


            <RadioButton

                android:id="@+id/createevent_visibility_public"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/create_event_public_event"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/createevent_visibility_private"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/create_event_private_event"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/createevent_visibility_ppv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/create_event_ppv"/>

        </RadioGroup>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ppv_panel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="@string/create_event_ppv_section"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ppv.currency.layout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <com.myapp.ui.AutoCompleteCombo
                        android:id="@+id/ppv.currency"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/create_event_ppv_currency">
                    </com.myapp.ui.AutoCompleteCombo>
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ppv.price.layout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/ppv.price"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/create_event_ppv_price"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/ppv_group"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="16dp">

                <RadioButton

                    android:id="@+id/ppv_all"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/create_event_ppv_allcountries"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/ppv_allexcept"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/create_event_ppv_except"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/ppv_only"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/create_event_ppv_some"/>

            </RadioGroup>


            <com.myapp.countries.CountriesMultiCombo
                android:id="@+id/create.ppv.countrylist"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/separator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/general_info"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-32dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:background="@color/colorDivider"
            />


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/geoblock_panel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="@string/geo_blocking_settings_title"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />


            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/geo_radiogroup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="16dp">

                <RadioButton

                    android:id="@+id/geo_none"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/geo_none"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/geo_blockonly"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/geo_block_only"/>


                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/geo_blockexcept"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/geo_block_all_except"/>

            </RadioGroup>


            <com.myapp.createevent.countries.CountriesMultiCombo
                android:id="@+id/create.geo.countrylist"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
                />

        </LinearLayout> <Button
        android:id="@+id/test_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CLICK ME"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Note that if I select the option manually (like I did with the second example in the image) I get the proper result. Its only if I do it programmatically that its missing the inner circle.

```
   public class TestFragment extends Fragment {


        private Unbinder mUnbinder;


        @BindView(R.id.createevent_visibility_public)
        RadioButton mVisibilityPublic;

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View inflate = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_advanced_opts, container, false);
            mUnbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, inflate);
            return inflate;

        }
        public static TestFragment newInstance(int tvId, int eventId) {

            TestFragment testFragment = new TestFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(TV_ARGUMENT, tvId);
            args.putInt(EVENTID_ARGUMENT, eventId);
            testFragment.setArguments(args);

            return testFragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            mVisibilityPublic.setChecked(true);
        }

   }
```

Comment: post your layout code as well as selector if any

Comment: have you even read the question?

Comment: share your XML file.

Comment: @HemantParmar there you have it

Comment: @MichelReap use property android:buttonTint="@color/green", in your radion button, and remove all these  mVisibilityPublic.performClick();
    mVisibilityPublic.setActivated(true);
    mVisibilityPublic.invalidate();
    mVisibilityPublic.requestLayout();.

Comment: @HemantParmar buttonTint is a feature of the API 21, if I remember correctly it doesn't work on previous versions, even with the Support Library

Comment: How do you set the colour to your button?

Comment: I dont, i jus assing the colorAccent on my theme and the color is put by Android

Comment: @Eselfar yes but you can ignore this, code will run, try this.

Comment: You can do this simply using `xml` by adding `android:checked="true"` to the radiobutton view you need checked. Then utilize `setOnCheckedChangeListener` of the radio group to handle the check states of the various radio buttons. Doing `((RadioButton)my_radio_group.findViewById(R.id.createevent_visibility_public)).setChecked(true);` should work too.

Comment: I cannot use XML, if I could I would, I only know the value in runtime

Comment: @MichelReap What do you mean by value?

Comment: I only know which button needs to be pressed in runtime. I already do setChecked, its on the first line on my question.

Comment: Post the code block where the radio group and buttons are referenced and used.

Comment: @codeFreak I just did that

Comment: Works fine to me. What is your device? Is it a real one or an emulator? And what is the Android version?

Comment: @Eselfar I tested on a Nexus 6P and on Google Pixel, with Android 7 and 8 respectively

Comment: I just created a simplified version my fragment and posted the entire XML